# JOIN self in MikroORM query Builder

Tags: mikro-orm

I would like to do this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `gps_log`                                           -- Same table
    WHERE log_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 232324324 MINUTE)
) as g
JOIN (SELECT MAX(gps_log_id) as gps_id, consignment_consignment_id
      FROM `gps_log`                                                   -- Same table
      GROUP BY consignment_consignment_id
     ) AS max ON max.gps_id = g.gps_log_id
```

but with MikroORM's query builder. I have read the docs and could not get it working with explicit joining.

My current solution is to `getKnex` instance and calling the raw sql. However I felt that it is unclean and still could not get it working:

```
const qb = this.em.createQueryBuilder(GpsLog);
const knex = qb.getKnexQuery(); // instance of Knex' QueryBuilder

knex.select("*")
    .fromRaw(
        "(SELECT * FROM `gps_log` WHERE log_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 232324324 MINUTE)) as g"
    )
    .joinRaw(
        "(SELECT MAX(gps_log_id) as gps_id, consignment_consignment_id FROM `gps_log` GROUP BY consignment_consignment_id) AS max ON max.gps_id = g.gps_log_id"
    )

const res = await this.em.getConnection().execute(knex);
const result = res.map(a => this.em.map(GpsLog, a));


return result;
```

For reference, here is my entity table:

```
@Entity()
export class GpsLog {

    /* SQL properties */
    @PrimaryKey({ hidden: true })
    gpsLogId!: number;

    @Property({ type: types.double })
    long!: string;
    
    @Property({ type: types.double })
    lat!: string;

    @Property()
    logTime: Date;


    /* JSON Formatter */
    @Property({ persist: false })
    get self() {
        return `/consgts/${this.consignment}/logs/${this.gpsLogId}`;
    }

    @Property({ persist: false })
    get consgt() {
        return `/consgts/${this.consignment}`;
    }


    /* SQL Relationships */
    @ManyToOne(() => Consignment, { mapToPk: true, hidden: true })
    consignment!: Consignment;
}
```